# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSafariViewController"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to integrate Google sign in into my iOS app. I have followed instructions mentioned by Google.

I have added SafariService.framework as well.

Still I am getting this error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSafariViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
```

How to fix this issue?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is your deployment target? SFSafariViewController is only available in iOS 9. And also check the linker flag -ObjC.

Comment: You need to be careful with `-ObjC` as it can cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: These are my linker flags: `-Objc -fobjc-arc -all_load`

Comment: My deployment target is set to 7.0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue. But my problem was i haven't included the SafariServices framework.

I added it as required and it worked fine.

Make sure you have the next configuration:

- Disabled BITE_CODE
- Added all needed frameworks
- The linker flag -ObjC (not -Objc)
- Added the needed url types
- Imported GoogleSignIn.h
- GoogleServices-Info.plist imported in your target

In my configuration i'm using 7.0 as deployment target

Hope it helps.
Regards

Comment: @esefire need more description on the point "GoogleServices-Info.plist imported in your target"..

Answer (score 16):

Since the SafariServices framework is only available on iOS9 and above, is it possible that you are trying to run this on a device with iOS lower than that? If so, is it possible that when you added the framework, you added it as required (making it impossible for the app to run on older versions of iOS)? Try setting it as optional (attaching an image to better explain what I mean).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with your solution but i am getting same error. The device i am trying to run the app has iOS version 8.2.