# Updating Google AdMob SDK from 7.7.0 to 7.8.0 Undefined Symbols Error

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have updated my Google AdMob SDK from 7.7.0 to 7.8.0. After that I am getting this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSafariViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(flat-x86_64)
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have added all these frameworks:

```
AdSupport,
AudioToolbox,
AVFoundation,
CoreGraphics,
CoreMedia,
CoreTelephony,
EventKit,
EventKitUI,
MediaPlayer,
MessageUI,
StoreKit,
SystemConfiguration
```

Before I updated this SDK it was working fine. This is in my Framework Search Path in Build Phases

**$(inherited)**

**$(PROJECT_DIR)/SDKs**

**$(PROJECT_DIR)**

**$(PROJECT_DIR)/SDKs/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.8.0**

[image: linked framework]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 "\_OBJC\_CLASS\_$\_SFSafariViewController"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880661/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-objc-class-sfsafariviewcontroller)

Comment: Error is different. It was for Google Sign In and my error is for Google AD Mob

Comment: include `SafariServices framework` and check once

Comment: I tried it, but getting the same error

Comment: run once in device and check

Comment: Running in device giving me this error **ld: framework not found SafariServices
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Comment: I have already added safariServices.framework. and I have also added one screenshot for linked binaries

Comment: `SFSafariViewController` is only available in 9.0 and later. Are you targeting an earlier iOS?

Comment: Did you install the framework via Cocoa Pods?

Comment: Yes. I am targeting 8.0 @Daniel Storm

Comment: No.. I installed framework manually

Comment: Try linking the framework as "Optional" and not "Required" under your Build Settings. The `SafariServices` framework requires iOS 9.0 or later

Comment: Than What is the solution. I want to target for iOS 8.0+

Answer (score 17):

I have added:
SafariServices.framework
CoreBluetooth.framework
It is working

Comment: It works for me.  It's a little weird. My many targets on the same workspace with almost the same project structure. Only one of them need  SafariServices and CoreBluetooth,  this one use "FBSDKLoginKit", and others do not.

Answer (score 1):

In version 7.8.0 new dependencies to the frameworks CoreBluetooth and SafariServices were added, so adding these solved the issue this time.

The GoogleMobileAds SDK (aka AdMob SDK) has many dependencies and they are being added (and sometimes removed) in successive releases. For instance, JavaScriptCore framework is a new dependency starting with version 7.13.0 released on 2016-10-17. If you run into this issue again check for updates to the framework dependencies in the release notes log:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/release-notes

Comment: Wish that link worked but Google is changing their documentatino so often, it's 404