# Admob error compiling in swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have followed all the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start) manually and with pods and yet I always have a similar issue, an error like this one:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSafariViewController", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(flat-x86_64)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added all of the frameworks manually:

```
AdSupport.framework  
AudioToolbox.framework  
AVFoundation.framework  
CoreGraphics.framework  
CoreTelephony.framework  
EventKit.framework  
EventKitUI.framework  
MessageUI.framework  
StoreKit.framework  
SystemConfiguration.framework  
including safariservices and corebluetooth
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: then looks like linker problem, clear all framework list and add again

Comment: i will try it again , but i try it in two different projets

Comment: if you use pod file you will do it easier [example of your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880661/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-objc-class-sfsafariviewcontroller)

Comment: If you have modules enabled then including all these frameworks manually is not needed. The SDK will link against them and be imported automatically.

Comment: i will try it ty!!! BTW i dont have BITE_CODE in build options any idea?

Comment: i was using xcode 6.3.1 i'm updating right now

Answer (score 0):

YES problem solved when i update XCODE to the last version