# Showing Issues : Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I am struggling for test app on device(iPhone 5). But, facing issue of:

> Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64.

Here is the attached screen shoot
[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880661/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-objc-class-sfsafariviewcontroller

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and then build?