# objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(please_link_SafariServices.framework_.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

I getting this error while integrating google plus . I face this issue from last two days . Please help me anyone

Answer (score 0):

In your your project's settings -> under target -> General -> Embedded Binaries -> `add SafariServices Framework`!

Or

In your Project's settings -> under target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries -> add `SafariServices Framework` !

And your issue will be solved!

Comment: which xcode are you using ? you should refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880661/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-objc-class-sfsafariviewcontroller)