# Objective-C linker can't find references to Core UIKit symbols

Tags: xcode, objective-c

## Trying to solve:

My `AppDelegate` creates a member variable `something` which I need access to in my `ViewDelegate`.

## My Implementation:

#### AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include "extern_lib.hpp"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) some::Something *something;

@end
```

---

#### AppDelegate.mm

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#include "extern_lib.hpp"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate {

}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    _something = new some::Something();

    return YES;
} 

@end
```

---

#### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@end
```

---

#### ViewController.mm

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.something;
    // use something
}


@end
```

---

#### extern_lib.hpp

```
#ifndef extern_lib_h
#define extern_lib_h

namespace some {

class Something {
public:
    Something() {}
    ~Something() {}
};

}

#endif /* extern_lib_h */
```

---

## Issue:

My issue is that the linker isn't finding basic core UI components and I'm really lost as to why.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIApplication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_UIApplicationMain", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not linking in the UIKit framework.

Go to project settings > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries >

I needed to add UIKit.Framework in this case.

Link that helped me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880661/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-objc-class-sfsafariviewcontroller